# Saving diligently, but the amount of retirement fund seems too much

Tags: retirement, early-retirement, south-korea

I recently achieved 100 million KRW (South Korean Won, about 86,000 USD) after a bit less than 5 years of work. I'm somewhat proud of myself for being diligent, but I'm afraid if this is not enough.

I'm definitely not a professional in accounting or investing, but I did very crude math myself with these parameters (all in KRW and inflation-adjusted):

- Current(Year-end)

  - Age: 30
  - Investment input: 83,281,657 - I used a personal accounting app to get this value. I think it is accurate enough, but not perfect.
  - Investment value: 102,386,242
- Expected

  - Annual investment: 16,800,000 - About a half of my income
  - Buffer fund: 43,200,000 - Additional fund in case of emergency
  - Annual withdrawal: 21,600,000 - National Pension Service claimed that proper living costs for a couple is about this much in early 2014. I'm single, but I want to be prepared.
  - Annual real return rate: 2.00%
  - Tax on profit: 15.40% - Over-simplified.
  - Life expectancy: 90

And this graph is the result.

[image: Estimated retirement fund investment]

According to this, I can retire at age 58. But there are things I'm worried about.

- The tax is too hard for me, so I used a VERY simplified single tax rate.
- I like my work, but I don't want to work for that long. I don't know what I can work at that age.
- I'm working on IT. I heard this line of work has an early retirement age. Working until I can retire seems an optimistic expectation
- I could invest about half of my income only because I'm living with my parents. My parents don't mind about this, but I can't expect this would last forever.
- I don't have a car or a house for myself. (A car is optional here, but you never know.)
- My homemade calculation can be wrong, which might mislead me to false hope/fear.
- Considering my self and my future spouse is already big. But what about children, educations, and medicals... It almost a horror to me.

My point is, even if I do my best, retirement still looks hard. Can you give me some wise words of yours to achieve my retirement?

Comment: Won't you also receive some benefit from state run pension/retirement plans?

Comment: Why does the red line in the graph start at age 30 instead of the normal Korean retirement age?

Comment: "I heard this line of work has early retirement age."  It's highly unlikely that you'll still be doing at age 60  **exactly** what you're doing at age 30, but it's perfectly reasonable that you'll still be doing **something** in IT.  (I started out as a programmer, but have been a DBA for 20 years.)

Comment: @HartCO I do and I expects it. I was too careful so didn't put it to my calculation.

Comment: @RonJohn The red line is the money I need to retire. So, the redline on 30 means I need that much money to retire at 30. I expect to retire at 58, when the red and purple lines cross.

Comment: @RonJohn And the reason I draw the red line from 30(my age) is... I wanted to see if I can retire earlier than the normal retirement age. It is easier to think that the line starts from 90 backwards, increasing.

Comment: 2% real returns seems like a conservative estimate to me, even when accounting for inflation and taxes. But that depends on how you are investing the money (are low-cost global index funds available in Korea?). I also don't think the "Expected Retirement Fund" line should be a *line* since it can be invested further until you need to make a withdrawal. There is some fund size beyond which you can live indefinitely only from the returns. With your numbers: 1.3 billion KRW (50× required income), would be smaller with better returns (only 25× assumed by US-centric guides)

Comment: You can make all of the projections that you want to but the reality is that a multitude of different things (good and bad) are going to happen between now and your retirement date.  You can't project now with any accuracy if you will be able to retire at 58.  The best that you can do is work, save as much as you can and invest wisely.  As you approach 45, 50 or 55, you'll have a much better idea if and when retiring will be  feasible.

Comment: 58 sounds like a slightly early retirement age. I always hear 65 and with longer life expectancies, they are considering moving the standard to 70 where I am from.

Comment: This analysis seems plausible but the assumption is, as you note, that your income and expenses stay the same. In your country and line of work, is there an expectation that your income will rise as you become a more experienced worker?  Are you expecting to have big increases in your expenses, by, say, having children?  Those seem to be missing from your analysis.

Comment: @amon You are right about me being conservative. Being careful is good, but maybe I'm over-doing it. I'm doing my best to use global index funds. MSCI ACWI is one of them. The annual fee of global index funds is about 0.55%. I'll think about the "Expected Retirement Fund" curve. Thank you.

Comment: @BobBaerker Right. Perhaps changing my mindset is also needed? Like enjoying my daily life and work for this long-run. Not that I'm not enjoying it right now, but maybe I should focus less future. What do you think? And thank you for the comment.

Comment: @user253751 It is. But retiring early is one of my major goals. Are you saying the goal should be more relaxed?

Comment: @EricLippert A good increase is guaranteed by the previous negotiation. But after that, maybe not much - a bit more than inflation rates. And about the children and other big expenses... that is exactly what I'm afraid of right now. Considering just my self and my future spouse is already big, but children, educations, medicals... the amount of retirement fund seems too much. That's one of the reasons why I'm being conservative with my calculation. Is retirement even possible?

Comment: @user2652379 - You should try to enjoy life regardless of your circumstances.  I can't tell you how to balance that with working.  Having retired well before 58, all I can offer is that you put your nose to the grindstone during the accumulation phase and when you reach a certain point, you'll know that you can retire.  My 'work' now is full time investing and trading because not only does the additional income help me to avoid spending down my nest egg but I enjoy it as well. It works for me.  You have to figure out what works for you.

Comment: If I read the OP right, this assumes that your salary remains the same until you are 58. It almost certainly will not.